# How to route isc-dhcp-server logs to their own file

Tags: logging, systemd-journald, dhcpd

The logging in systemd's journal is getting spammed by logging from dhcpd.

I am running isc-dhcp-server and would like to prevent the log ending up in the journal, and instead go to its own file.

I had a similar issue with apparmor, but that was rectified by installing `auditd` which reroutes the logs for me.

Is there an equivalent for doing this for dhcpd logs?

OS: Ubuntu 22.04

dhcpd: 4.4.1-2.3ubuntu2.3

### UPDATE

What I tried:

Add to /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf

```
log-facility local7;
```

And add to /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf

```
local7.* /var/log/dhcpd.log
```

But all this accomplished was doubling the logging to 2 different destinations. I want the logs to the `/var/log/syslog` to stop and only log to `/var/log/dhcpd.log` destination.

Answer (score 0):

At the very bottom of 50-default.conf, you should have the following lines:

```
# comment out the following line to allow messages through. Doing so
# means you'll also get messages in /var/log/syslog
& stop
```

If you don't, add and restart rsyslog.

Comment: I added those lines, and did `systemctl restart rsyslog` but I still get the log entries in both the dhcpd log and the syslog.

Comment: Try adding local7.none to catch-all filter:

`*.*;auth,authpriv.none;kern.none;mail.none;cron.none,local7.none -/var/log/syslog`

Comment: I think it is slowly getting there... they stopped appearing in syslog, but still show up in journalctl output?